# How to deal with array value in query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, url

I have a url which takes an array of topicName query like this

localhost:3000/api/?topicName=mobile&topicName=website

and sometimes topicName only has one value like this

```
localhost:3000/api/?topicName=mobile
```

and below is how I use that query values in node JS

```
let topicNameArray = [];
topicNameArray = req.query.topicName
let value = topicNameArray.map(function(e) {
return new RegExp(e, "i");
})
```

The problem I am facing is when the array query only has one value, my app will receive this message

```
"message": "topicNameArray.map is not a function
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution to deal with this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use `console.log(topicNameArray)` to check `topicNameArray` is array or string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to reform your querystring to mitigate the error you are experiencing.

Currently I think you have a query string like such: `localhost:3000/api/?topicName=mobile&topicName=website` Here you have one query argument `topicName` and this is essentially a string. So when you have multiple instance of `topicName` key in your querystring you should have been replacing the the value at this key with the last instance of it in the querystring. So to send an array of values use the querystring structure as following: `localhost:3000/api/?topicName[]=mobile&topicName[]=website` **(notice the square brace.)**

Later you can check if the query argument is an array or not. You can use `Array.isArray` function for that. Then you can perform your exception handling on later parts.

Comment: The Array.isArray is what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could check if topicName is an array using one of the following and convert it to an array like this

```
topicNameArray = req.query.topicName
if(req.query.topicName.constructor !== Array) {
   topicNameArray = [req.query.topicName];
}
```

Or like this,

```
topicNameArray = req.query.topicName
if(!topicNameArray.length) { // only arrays have length property
   topicNameArray = [req.query.topicName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `topicNameArray` is being reassigned to `req.query.topicName` which is actually a string when only one `topicName` is given. You can check the type of `req.query.topicName` and if its a string turn it into an array like so:

```
let topicNameArray = req.query.topicName;   // assume its an array
if (typeof topicNameArray === "string")  { // check if it's a string
  topicNameArray = [req.query.topicName];   // convert to array
}
```

or if you prefer the look of the ternary operator:

```
let topicName = req.query.topicName;
let topicNameArray = (typeof topicName === "string") ? [topicName] : topicName;
```